Providing a link to a question and the system recognizing your user?
I am thinking about providing a link to a question, but I have one question before doing so. How can you provide the link with it recognizing your user? I know that in area 51 you can create your own unique url so that it will recognize that you referred all users who clicked that link, but what about in a beta/launched site? Apparently you can earn this badge if your link gets clicked on by 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days. But how can it tell which user is providing the link? Is there something extra I have to do? If so, what?

Please do announce your questions or indeed answers - it helps get the word out and will increase awareness of the site :)

The format used by the "link" function is https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/<question ID>/<user ID>, but you can type it yourself as well.
Note that answers and questions share the same ID space, so you can also refer to answers that way — the "link" function there seems to forget to include your user ID.
